# Adding a faculty as a co-author

Tags: publications, authorship

I and two other student, did a course project and it has been accepted for publication in an international conference. I am confused now that whether I should add his name as a co-author or acknowledge him in acknowledgements ?
I would like to share that though, the entire implementation and writing the paper was done by us, we were student of his class and the work was produced as a part of course project.

My field is Computer Science.

Edit: As F'x suggests, that I should ask the instructor. What would be an appropriate way to do so given that his name was not added as co-author before acceptance.(We were confident about the work but were not sure about the acceptance. The conference management software was EDAS and it spams email of all co-authors which we wanted to avoid in his case)

Comment: Discuss it with your teacher.

Comment: The right time to ask this question was **before** you submitted. But better late than never.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding *“given that his name was not added as co-author before acceptance”*: **ask him ASAP**. Be honest, be apologetic, explain clearly the situation and the reasons you did not want to add his name beforehand, but also be very clear that you realize now it was a mistake not to discuss it at the time, and that you made the mistake due to your lack of experience in academic publishing.

Comment: And the vast majority of academics I've met will be happy with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

If he/she supervised your work, and/or read your paper, and/or somehow gave his/her contribution to your paper, **I think that yes**, you should add his/her name as author.

Answer (score 1):

Co-authorship depends on the person and (sometimes) internal rules. For instance, during my PhD it was common for the professors to consider reading a paper + giving feedback as contribution worth authorship. Some of them even thought that they deserve authorship just because they talked to you about your idea:) 
During my Masters (at another university) my supervisor did not only read the paper, but also corrected some errors in the formulas and checked the experimental results. When I put him as a co-author, he asked to remove his name motivating this as "I just did the work a normal supervisor will do".

So, as others suggest - do ask the professor ASAP.
P.S. Many professors will not fund your trip to a conference if their name is not on the paper unless explicitly agreed beforehand:)